# Le plus approprié vs. les plus appropriés

Tags: grammaire, accord

Quelle est la forme correcte entre:

1. Dans quels cas X ou Y est-il le plus appropriés?
2. Dans quels cas X ou Y sont-ils le plus approprié?
3. Dans quels cas X ou Y sont-ils les plus appropriés?

Quelle règle grammaticale justifie d'employer la forme correcte?

Merci d'avance.

Answer (score 1):

- La première phrase est incorrecte du fait du *s* à la fin de *approprié*. Sans ce *s*, la phrase est correcte.
- La deuxième phrase est incorrecte car il y a une non concordance entre le sujet (*ils*, donc pluriel) et l'attribut du sujet (*le plus approprié*, singulier)
- La troisième phrase est correcte

Deux formes peuvent être correctes selon le sens que l'on veut donner à cette phrase. Dans la première phrase, le *ou* devient exclusif : une seule des propositions parmi X et Y est appropriée, contrairement à la troisième phrase où les deux propositions peuvent être appropriées en même temps